# passing model object to view in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have been trying to pass a model object to be evaluated in my template but had no luck.   I tried the following but had no luck

dashboardmodel.js

```
var myMod = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
     name: "mo",
     age: "10"
   }
});
```

myview.js

```
         var dashView = Backbone.View.extend({

         el: '.content-area',

         this.mymodel = new myMod({}), 

         template: _.template(dashBoardTemplate, this.mymodel),
         initialize: function() {
                    },

                    render: function() {
                        this.$el.html(this.template);
                        return this;
                    }

// more javascript code.............
```

dahboard.html

```
<p> Hello <%= name %> </p>
```

PS: I am using the underscore template engine

Comment: Just edit your template to make it cachable and in your render function pass model.toJSON() or model.attributes, do not pass model itself. [BACKBONE DOCS](http://backbonejs.org/#View-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get properties of a Backbone Model with the getter syntax, so you need to rewrite your template to:

```
<p> Hello <%= obj.get('name') %> </p>
```

Or you need to convert your model into a plain JS object when calling `_.template` what you can do with the `.toJSON()` (which creates a clone of the model) or `.attributes` property:

```
template: _.template(dashBoardTemplate, this.mymodel.toJSON())
```

Side note: you should consider to move the template rendering logic into your view. Because your current code render your template when your view is declared and not when you call the `render` method. So you might get unexpected result. So your code you look like this:

```
template: _.template(dashBoardTemplate), //only compile the template
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.mymodel.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks the second approach worked like charm

Answer (score 5):

In addition , your way to pass a model to a view is not flexible, because you would pass an instance of your model, instead of a default model. Thus, you might want to single out

```
this.mymodel = new myMod({}),
```

(btw, above line gives me error message in my chrome browser because of "=" sign)

Then, suppose you have an instance A:

```
A = new myMod({"name": "World", "age":100})
```

Then pass it to your view as:

```
myview = new dashView({mymodel: A})
```

One more step, you have to do is to call render function:

```
myview.render();
```

Here's a complete solution:

```
<html>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="backbone.js"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/template" id="dashBoardTemplate">
<p> Hello <%= name %> </p>
</script>
<div class="content-area">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myMod = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
     name: "mo",
     age: "10"
   }
});

var dashView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.content-area',
    template: _.template($("#dashBoardTemplate").html()),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
mymod = new myMod({"name": "World", "age":100});
myview = new dashView({model:mymod});  
myview.render();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to study backone.js, please read this open source book which get me started:

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/